# Interfaces casting dilema

Tags: java, interface, casting

I have an awkward problem with this (propably) simple casting example. Could you please help me?

```
public class Example1 {

interface ParentIf{}
interface ChildIf extends ParentIf {}
interface OtherIf {}

class ParentCl {}
class ChildCl extends ParentCl {}
class OtherCl {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChildIf cI = null;
        ParentIf pI = null;
        OtherIf oI = null;
        ChildCl cC = null;
        ParentCl pC = null;
        OtherCl oC = null;

        cI = (ChildIf)oI; //case1 - fine

        cC = (ChildCl)oC; //case2 - inconvertible types

        cI = (ChildIf)oC; //case3 - fine
    }
}
```

But more awkward is that I don't know why the other two statements are fine.

I can't see any connection between OtherIf and ChildIf. So how is possible to cast the OtherIf to the ChildIf when there is no "extend" between these two interfaces in case1?

Answer (score 2):

```
cI = (ChildIf)oI;
```

is fine because `oI` could be an instance of a class that implements both ChildIf and OtherIf.

```
cI = (ChildIf)oC;
```

is fine because `oC` could be an instance of a class that extends `OtherClass` anec implements `ChildIf`.

Comment: I am still just a little bit confused. "Could" means that at this moment oI is not an instance of a class that implements both ChildIf and OtherIf but IntelliJ "knows" that it could be? Sorry I can't see it :/

Comment: oI is a variable which refers to an object of type `OtherIf`. The compiler doesn't care about the concrete type of the object at runtime. It cares about the declared type of the variable: OtherIf. Is it possible for a type to implement both ChildIf and OtherIf? Yes, it's possible. So the cast might succeed, so it makes sense.